# Integration by substitution (Why can't I use $u =\sin^2 x$ for $\int \sin^2 x \cos x \space dx$ )

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that I have to use $$u=sinx$$ and so we have $$du = cosx dx$$ hence we have $$dx = \frac{du}{cosx}$$ and so we have $$\int u^2cosx \frac{du}{cosx}$$ which is equal to $$\int u^2 \space du$$ which is $$\frac{u^3}{3} = \frac{sin^3x}{3} + C$$

However, If I used $$u = sin^2x$$, I will have $$du =2sinxcosx dx$$ and so $$dx= \frac{du}{2sinxcosx}$$ and so The integral becomes $$\int ucosx \frac{du}{2sinxcosx}$$ which is equal to $$\int \frac{u}{2sinx} \space du$$

and since we know that $u = sin^2x$ so we have  $$\int \frac{sinx}{2} \space du$$

But then I am stuck here, I feel like going in circles !!

Comment: Since $u=\sin^2(x)\implies \sin(x)=\sqrt{u}$. Therefore your last line would become:$$\int\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}du$$

Comment: yes that makes a lot of sense !! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned comments into answer as requested by OP

Since $u=\sin^2(x)\implies\sin(x)=\sqrt{u}$. Therefore your last line would become:$$\int\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}du$$

**NOTE:** @Mark has pointed out a very good reason as to why this is not as good a substitution to use as $u=\sin(x)$

Answer (score 2):

We could write that $\sin x=\sqrt{u}$; this suggests that $u=\sin^2 x$ is not a good replacement... for example is it $\sin x=+\sqrt{u}$ or $\sin x=-\sqrt{u}$?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the substitution $u=\sin^2x$, then $du=2\sin x\cos xdx$ and

$$\begin{align}
\int \sin^2x \cos x dx &= \int   \frac{u}{2\sqrt{u}}\;du\\
&=\frac12 \int \sqrt{u}\;du\\
&=\left(\frac12\right) \left(\frac23\right) u^{3/2}+C\\
&=\frac13 \sin^3 x+C
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answer :)